# Why FullGC can not release physical memory(RES)?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Below is the **RES** growth curve：
[image]

then is the **Old gen** Occupancy Fraction：
[image]

Forcing Full GC by jmap,the Old gen indeed decreased but the RES has been growing...

pmap result:

[image]

What's the meaning of **anon**,it is non-heap memory?

**Edit**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The heap used just about 500MB,but the RSS exceed 15GB,the pmap shows that many **anon** about 65MB.

My question is What might consumed memory outside of heap? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What's the meaning of anon,it is non-heap memory?

anon just means it has been `mmap()`'d with `MAP_ANON`. Given the RSS it's probably the heap.

> Why FullGC can not release physical memory(RES)?

You have to distinguish between maximum heap size, heap occupancy and committed heap size.

- maximum heap size is address space that will be reserved up front but not necessarily backed by pages
- committed heap size will be backed by pages and usually zeroed/pretouched. this generally is what affects your RSS
- occupancy is the fraction that actually contains objects instead of zeros

Only when the committed heap size goes down pages *can* be released back to the OS.

Decomitting/yielding memory to the OS depends on GC algorithm, JVM version and tuning parameters (pause time goals, `MaxHeapFreeRatio`).

---

The other regions you list are probably direct ByteBuffer allocations but they could also be other allocations from native libraries.
Examining a heap dump for `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer` instances should provide further insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi.The problem is My -Xmx is 4G but now RSS has risen to 17G

Comment: your question does not reflect that

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's JVM have multiple algorithm for managing memory.
Some of them can return unused memory pages to OS, other cannot.

Default algorithm (parallel collector) never returns memory to OS.

Following two algorithms can return memory to OS

- Serial GC (single threaded mark sweep compact)
- G1

You have find summary of available algorithms and related JVM options [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.